# How to asynchronously query a large amount of data with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to query 400k rows from a `mysql` database, by getting 10 at a time. To do that asynchronously I need to use a recursion like this:

```
var migrate = function(offset, size) {
  Mysql.query(query, [offset, size], function(err, rows) {
    if (!err && rows.length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        // Pretend doing something and get next batch.
        migrate(offset + size, size);
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
};

migrate(0, 10);
```

The problem is, the first call of `migrate()` creates a child callback of itself, and all of them stay in the memory till the last `migrate()` is finished.

The only solution that comes to mind is to run it synchronously inside `while` loop.

Can you please advise how to do that properly? Thanks.

Comment: Find a a way to reduce the amount of calls needed, by either writing more complex sql (so you dont need 400k rows) or asking for more rows at the same time. Or only fetch the rows you'll use immediately. If you need 400k rows on the front end at exactly the same time, there's probably a design issue. You could also rewrite the function so that it isn't recursive, but hands off to a different function that will handle the data returned and will call migrate again. If you clone or dereference the returned data, the prev ajax calls should be able to be garbage collected and free up memory.

Answer (score 0):

In current example with [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) module it can be done by querying all records without chunking and using with [Streaming query rows](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#streaming-query-rows). It will run queries one by one, once result is processed.

```
Mysql.query(sql).on('result', function(row) {
  Mysql.pause();
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Pretend doing something.
    Mysql.resume();
  }, 1000);
});
```

But (!), `result` callback should not have any closure variables, because in that case these variables will be staying the memory. I did some benchmarks, it's how I know about it, can't explain it otherwise.

In general, if you need to process a large amount of data, doesn't matter is it a mysql or something else, I would recommend to:

1. Use [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).
2. Use [process.nextTick()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args).
3. Do not use closures.
4. Do not use recursions.

Comment: Good advice. Technically, you could use closures and recursion if you used streams properly. They only become problematic when they are retaining large amounts of memory, which cannot happen if you use streams

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SynJS](https://github.com/amaksr/SynJS) - it allows to run javascript code synchronously:

```
var SynJS = require('synjs');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'tracker',
  password : 'tracker123',
  database : 'tracker'
});


function myMigrate(modules,connection) {
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        connection.query("SELECT CONCAT('processing data batch #',?) as res",[i], function(err, rows, fields) {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log(i,rows[0].res);
              modules.SynJS.resume(_synjsContext);
        });
        SynJS.wait();
    }
};

var modules = {
        SynJS:  SynJS,
        mysql:  mysql,
};

SynJS.run(myMigrate,null,modules,connection,function () {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Result would be:

```
0 'processing data batch #0'
1 'processing data batch #1'
2 'processing data batch #2'
3 'processing data batch #3'
done
```